# I have a problem the random.choice() function as it prints one LETTER in a list of WORDS

Tags: python

I am new to python and programming in general and I was trying to make a hangman game. I downloaded a dictionary text file and opened it in pycharm and I applied the random.choice() function on it and it only printed a letter of a random word in the .txt file:

```
import random

f = open ("/home/ar/Downloads/sowpods.txt")

sowpods = f.read()

sowpods = random.choice(sowpods)

print(sowpods)
```

Comment: you don't have a list of words. `f.read()` returns a single string with the entire contents of the file, and a random choice out of a single string is a single character.  You can use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split it up into a list.

Comment: `sowpods = random.choice(sowpods.split())` Splitting the words by whitespace gives you a random word from the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to convert from a list of characters to a list of words. You can do this using `string.split()`.

```
import random

f = open ("/home/ar/Downloads/sowpods.txt")

sowpods = f.read().split()

sowpods = random.choice(sowpods)

print(sowpods)
```